# Enqueueing scripts and styles multiple CPTS

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to load several scripts and stylesheets into a plugin I am creating. I want to load scripts into multiple CPTs within admin. I have got this far:

```
function fhaac_admin_enqueue_scripts(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ( ($pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'post-new.php') && $typenow == 'fhaac' ){}
}
```

The scripts are being loaded into the fhaac, but nothing else. I am not sure how to add multiple CPTs. I tried adding them in an array, but it didn't work.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function that you can use, instead of globals. The [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function allows you to get the information associated with the current page.

One of its return values is `post_type`. So you can check against an array of post types to see if anyone matches.

```
function fhaac_admin_enqueue_scripts(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if (
        in_array( $screen->post_type, array('fhaac','blabla')) &&
        $screen->base == 'post'
     ) { // Do something }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a really simple work around:

**Load it everywhere and only run the code if the page matches**

For example, on my site I have a CPT named `projects` and on the body tag I have the following:

```
<body
    class="wp-admin wp-core-ui js   jetpack-connected  edit-php auto-fold admin-bar post-type-project branch-4-8 version-4-8 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us multisite customize-support sticky-menu svg">
```

So I know that my posts listing will match `body.edit-php`, and `body.post-type-project`

So for CSS:

```
body.post-type-project.edit-php .... {
    ....
}
```

And I can do the same check in javascript be it with jQuery